# node-forever seems not working as I expected

Tags: node.js, forever

```
// test.js

var util = require('util');

setTimeout(function () {
    util.puts('Throwing error now.');
    throw new Error('User generated fault.');
}, 200);
```

`$ forever start -l ./forever.log -o output.log -e err.log -m 5 -a start test.js`

I run the above command, and get:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: test_debug.js
```

I expect to get 5 error log, but actually I just get one in the err.log. It seems test.js just run one time other than 5 times.

Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the 1st warning:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
```

If your app can't stay up for more than a second (and yours would crush after 200ms), forever.js wouldn't try to restart it.

You can test it by either change the `setTimeout` to wait for 1001ms, or change the `minUptime` to something shorter than 200ms.

Comment: Thanks. I add `minUptime` and it works. But my json config doesn't work yet.

Comment: Please avoid asking two question in the same post. Please open a new question for the json issue, with the relevant command you used (you didn't mention the json path in the command line in this question).